# Where do I look for programs that run at login on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, .net-3.5

I recently bought an older refurbished laptop with Windows 10 on it and I disabled .NET 3.5 in Control Panel->Programs(if in Category View)->Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off. Now I get a prompt window every time I log in saying "An app on your PC needs the following Windows feature: .NET Framework 3.5(includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)". Where should I look to find which program is trying to run at login? I know about \Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\, but there are no programs in there. I also ran msconfig and there are no programs under the Startup tab.

Comment: For windows 10 - try in Task Manager - under the Start-up Tab?

Comment: I use sysinternals Autoruns. There are something like 26 different ways to autostart an application, and it checks quite a few of them. Windows doesn't often use the Startup folder for non-persistent tasks. that said, if you are seeing this on every login, your .net 3 install has not completed successfully, or is misconfigured.

Comment: @Darius I disabled some intel video card related services (hkcmd, igfxtray, and persistence module) that were showing on the Startup tab and now I do not the prompt any longer. I was sure I had looked there, but maybe I was under a standard rather than an Admin account ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few startup locations in Windows.

In your startup folder:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

In all users startup folder (ProgramData)

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

In the Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

---

Services (via Registry):

Do not modify the Registry manually unless you know what you are doing.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
```

---

In addition to the above, check the task scheduler (run **taskschd.msc**) and windows services (run **services.msc**) - as both can contain processes (or tasks) that auto start when you login.

---

I would **highly recommend using Startup Delayer** which is an excellent program (there is a freeware version) capable of editing all of the above with an easy to use interface.

You can find the program here: http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startup-delayer/

---

**Autoruns** is another great program to use and is part of Microsoft's Sysinternals toolset. It's available for download here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Answer (score 1):

Current user startup:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\      (> NT5.1)
%allusersprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\                (<=NT5.1)
```

All users startup:

```
%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\  (> NT5.1)
%allusersprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\                (<=NT5.1)
```

Current user registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

All users registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Registry services entries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
```

Better to disable/enable them using:

```
services.msc
```

There's a control panel applet that controls these locations, I am using it for many years now: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/startup_cpl.html